# One-way repeated measures anova

Tags: r, time-series, anova, repeated-measures, nested-data

I tried finding an answer to this question on this and other sites but to no avail - if I am missing something please excuse my inability to locate the answer!

Basically I have several dependent variables (`dv`) for two land management treatments (`treat`) measured quarterly (`season`). I know that I need to run a RM-ANOVA with season as a random effect, and so I am using the `lme` test in R. What I cant work out is whether I should be including season as a random variable like so:

```
lme <- lme(dv ~ treat, random = ~1|season, data=data)
```

or whether I should be nesting season within treatment like so:

```
lme <- lme(dv ~ treat, random = ~1|treat/season, data=data)
```

Many thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major update, based on your comment.

The code should be something like when using `lme` from `nlme`:

```
lme.model <- lme(dv ~ season * treat, random = ~1|rep, data=data)
```

where `rep` is a factor assigning unique codes to each of your 10 independent study sites (i.e., 5 per treatment), `season` is a factor indicating measurment quarter, and treatment is the treatment factor.

However, this will not give you a real ANOVA but a mixed model with one random effect (`rep`) and two fixed effects (`season` and `between`).

To fit a real ANOVA (namely one with one between- and one within-subjects factor, a so called split-plot design) you could use package [`afex`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/index.html):

```
require(afex)
anova <- ez.glm("rep", "dv", data = data, within = "season", between = "treat")
```

You could run this on each dv separately.

To analyze all dvs together you would need some multivariate analysis of which I am no expert.

---

Response prior to your comment:

If `treat` is your unit of observation (of which having two seems to be quite low), then the following code would be correct:

```
lme <- lme(dv ~ season, random = ~1|treat, data=data)
```

However, as said, having a repeated measures ANOVA with only two units of observation is pretty uncommon and seems a bad idea. If this is really your design (observed two treatments over several seasons), you are probably better off with other analyses, such as single-case analysis, e.g., [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Henrik, yes we have two treatments as I am comparing the effects of wildfire versus no wildfire on soils, and collected repeat samples over time. Why are you suggesting that season should be the fixed variable? Perhaps I should have been clearer that I am only really interested in comparing between the treatments (ie. fire vs. no fire)

Comment: What exactly did you measure within each treatment? And at what times?

Comment: I measured numerous dependent variables such as pH, EC, temperature, nutrient concentrations....the data were collected once per quarter (i.e. approx. every three months, but not exactly the same length of time between measurements). And there are 5 reps (independent study sites) for fire and no fire.

Comment: great - thanks for your assistance. I'll give the ez.glm a try as that sounds like what I need.

Comment: you can alo upvote my answer if you think it is useful (small normal distribution above the 0).

Comment: Henrik - when I try this I get the message: Error in terms.formula(formula, "Error", data = data) : 
  invalid term in model formula
For rep I have 1,1,1,1,1,1...10,10,10,10,10,10.
For season 1,2,3,4,5,6...
For treat 1s and 2s.
dv is a continuous variable.
Im not sure where im going wrong now - is there a way to post a datafile on here?

Comment: update from my last message:
anova <- ez.glm(id="id", dv="dv", data = data, within = "season", between = "treat")
 
seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: your help so far has been brilliant. I wondered if you could please explain how I might modify the approaches to consider this: so far I have kept things simple and used average data from my study reps [aka sites] on each sampling occasion (i.e. a total of 60 measures of each dv = 6x season, 2x treat, 5x reps [sites] per treat). I actually have a total of 300 measures of each dv (i.e. 6x season, 2x treat, 5x sites per treat, 5x reps per site/season). Is it possible to build in a between-site comparison, such that I can compare effects of site, treat and season? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this `R` command

```
lme <- lme( fixed = dv ~ treat + season , random = ~1 | id   , data=data)
```

where `id` is the identification of your records